How can I pass an array state to a parent component in React Native?
I have a modal component that renders a list with checkboxes. When I click on the checkbox, it adds the item to an empty array state. I am trying to pass that array to the component that will use it. But I can't pass the state in my component arguments and also have the state declared in the same component. How can I construct these arrays and pass them to where I can use them?
Modal component
const TechniqueSelectionModal = ({
  modalVisible,
  onBackPress,
  isLoading = false,
  value,
  selectedwaza, // this is a no-no
  setValue
}) => {

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  const [selectedwaza, setSelectedWaza] = useState([]) //  becasue of this
  const [dropdowndata, setDropdownData] = useState(allnagewaza)

  const selectItem = (item, index) => {
    const newData = [...dropdowndata];
    newData[index].checked = !item.checked;
    setChecked(!checked)
    setDropdownData(newData);
    
    // but I need to do this
    if(newData[index].checked) {
      setSelectedWaza([...selectedwaza, newData[index]])
    } else {
      setSelectedWaza(selectedwaza.filter((i) => i.title !== newData[index].title))
    }
    console.log(selectedwaza);
  }

  return (
    <Modal animationType="slide" visible={modalVisible} transparent={true}>
      <View>
        {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator size={70} color={colors.tertiary} />}

        {!isLoading && (
          <View>
            <View>
              <Text> Techniques </Text>
              <Pressable onPress={onBackPress} >
                <Icon name="close" size={24} color={activeColors.textcolor} />
              </Pressable>
            </View>
            
            <View style={styles.decisionRow}>
              <SearchField value={value} onChangeText={setValue}/>
              <View>
                {allnagewaza.map((item, index) => {
                  if(value === "" ) {
                    return null
                  } else if(
                      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) || 
                      item.english.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
                    ) 
                  {
                    return (
                      <View key={index} style={styles.searchitems}>
                        <View style={styles.metadata}>
                          <Image source={{ uri: `${URL}${item.thumbnail}` }}/>
                          <View>
                            <Text> {item.title} </Text>
                            <Text>{item.english}</Text>
                          </View>  
                        </View>
                        <View>
                          <Checkbox
                            mode="android"
                            status={item.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                            onPress={() => selectItem(item, index)}
                          />
                        </View>   
                      </View>
                    )
                  }
                })}
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};

Parent Component
//Reusable component
//Same problem here, I can't pass this to the main component below
const TestArea = ({waza, area, onButtonPress}) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [viewPosition, setViewPosition] = useState(0.5);
  const [waza, setWaza] = useState([]) // This is where I'm hoping to consume the `selectedwaza` state content from the modal so I can render it in my flatlist

  const ref = useRef(null);
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  let activeColors = colors[theme.mode]
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setWaza([...selectedwaza]) //  I've also tried injecting it this way, but it's not even leaving the modal component so I can't catch it here
  }, [index, viewPosition, selectedwaza])

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text> {area} </Text>   
        <Pressable onPress={onButtonPress}>
          <Icon name="plus" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
        </Pressable>
      </View>  
      <Animated.FlatList
        ref={ref}
        data={waza}
        horizontal
        initialNumToRender={10}
        initialScrollIndex={index}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={ITEM_SIZE}
        snapToOffsets={[...Array(waza.length).keys()].map(i => i * ITEM_SIZE)}
        decelerationRate={0}
        bounces={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          alignItems: 'flex-start',
        }}
        renderItem={
          ({item, index: fIndex}) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity 
                key={fIndex}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TechniqueDetails', {data: item})}
                style={{width:ITEM_SIZE}}>      
                <Animated.View>         
                  <Image source={{ uri: `${URL}${item.thumbnail}` }} />
                  <Text 
                    numberOfLines={2}
                    style={{
                      width: ITEM_SIZE - 10,
                      color:activeColors.textcolor, 
                      fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }}>  
                    {item.title} 
                  </Text>   
                </Animated.View>   
              </TouchableOpacity>   
            )
          }
        }
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const RokkyuRoute = () => {  
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [gokyoNoWaza, setGokyoNoWaza] = useState([]);
  const [kaeshiWaza, setKaeshiWaza] = useState([]);

  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View>
        <ScreenTitle title="Yellow Belt Test - Rokkyu"/>
      </View>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.routecontainer}>
          <View>
            <Text>Technical Test</Text>
            //The plan is to make reusable components holding flatlists with items collected inside the modal component. So the modal component needs to work for as many TestArea components as I want to make and they will all hold different stuff
            <TestArea 
              waza={gokyoNoWaza} 
              area="Nage Waza (Select 4 throws)" 
              onButtonPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}/>  

            <TestArea 
              waza={kaeshiWaza} 
              area="Kaeshi Waza (Select 2 counters)" 
              onButtonPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}/>  
          </View>
        </View>
        <TechniqueSelectionModal
          modalVisible={modalVisible}
          onBackPress={() => { setModalVisible(false); setValue(""); }}
          value={value}
          setValue={setValue}
        />     
        
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
};

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks
